# ODBC Connection to Remote server

Tags: odbc, unixodbc

Would I require an internet to establish an ODBC connection between an on-premises Linux server and cloud DB(e.g. Azure)?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand what you're asking, it is very difficult to establish a connection without a connection. Perhaps you could add some detail to your question that explain the background.

Comment: I need to use ODBC, but I'm not familiar with its requirements. Basically I need to establish  communication  between an on -premises  server and Azure Cosmos  DB without using Internet , is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to reach across the Internet to reach the Azure services.
If at home, little configuration is needed beyond using the IP address, port number, and username/password for the ODBC connection.
If in a workplace with a dedicated firewall, then you may need a rule added to allow your Linux server to make the connection as well as the previously mentioned ODBC settings.

Comment: Thanks. I thought ODBC has some capability to provide request/response to allow for direct access between the two end points without being exposed to the internet(HTTP/HTTPS). However , in the cloud this option seems not.

Comment: @rfm_369 HTTP/HTTPS is _not_ "internet"; ODBC does not use either; however, it needs the transport protocol and the physical infrastructure that the actual Internet provides. There are other ways to provide the transport protocol and the physical infrastructure apart from the Internet, if you're willing to pay.

Comment: Could you provide some examples/tools of using the transport protocol to establish ODBC connection in this scenario ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/expressroute/expressroute-erdirect-about

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on what @rfm_369 said, you also need to know your source and target database to configure odbc correctly, because each database may use a different odbc port to connect. ex. sql, db2, postsql etc.

Which databases are you trying to connect?

Then the next thing to look out for is what tool you are using to connect your on-primise to the cloud. except its a local cloud, you will need to have access through a firewall for the local server or device to access the cloud database system. So submit filters through your network team or firewall team to get to the cloud.

finally, once connectivity is establish based on your specific database odbc drivers settings, you will be good to start testing. Good luck.